# Getting "TypeError: X is not a function" when calling async method in promises chain

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise

I'm currently trying to create a small app getting info from a public transport API. I created some classes to represent the object and some of them (here, `Route`) contain async methods.
I can't figure out how to call them properly and keep getting TypeError on them.

Here is my test script:

```
import { TagHelper } from './modules/TagHelper';

function testMod() {
    TagHelper.getRouteInfo("C1")
        .then(C1 => C1.loadPatterns())
        .then(C1 => C1.loadStops())
        .then(C1 => console.log(C1))
    ;
}

testMod();
```

and here is my helper module:

```
import requestPromise = require('request-promise');

class Route {
    readonly id: string;
    readonly shortName: string;
    readonly longName: string;
    readonly mode: string;
    readonly color: number;
    readonly agencyName: string;
    patterns: Pattern[];
    stops: Stop[];

    constructor(id: string, shortName: string, longName: string, mode: string, color: string, agencyName: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.shortName = shortName;
        this.longName = longName;
        this.mode = mode;
        this.color = parseInt(color, 16);
        this.agencyName = agencyName;
    }

    async loadPatterns() {
        console.log("TEST");
        this.patterns = JSON.parse(await requestPromise("https://data.metromobilite.fr/otp/routers/default/index/routes/" + this.id + "/patterns"));
        return this;
    }

    async loadStops() {
        this.stops = JSON.parse(await requestPromise("https://data.metromobilite.fr/otp/routers/default/index/routes/" + this.id + "/stops"));
        return this;
    }
}

class Pattern {
    ...
}

class Stop {
    ...
}

const TagHelper = {

    getRouteInfo: async function(route_short_name: string, route_mode: string = null): Promise<Route> {
        const routes_data: Route[] = JSON.parse(await requestPromise("https://data.metromobilite.fr/otp/routers/default/index/routes"));
        for(let route of routes_data) {
            if (route.shortName.toUpperCase() === route_short_name.toUpperCase() && (route_mode === null || route_mode.toUpperCase() === route.mode.toLocaleUpperCase()))
                return route;
        }
        return null;
    }
};

export { TagHelper, Route, Pattern, Stop };
```

Edit: I just realize I didn't include the error so here it is:

```
(node:868) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: C1.loadPatterns is not a function
    at temp.ts:5:24
```

Comment: `routes_data` is not an array of `Route`. You don't have instances of Route class.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I just confused JSON objects and class instances. Thanks estus for pointing this out!

I fixed my mistake by modifying the `Route` class:

```
class Route {
    ...
    patterns: Pattern[];
    stops: Stop[];

    constructor(id: string, shortName: string, longName: string, mode: string, color: string, agencyName: string) {
        ...
        this.patterns = [];
        this.stops = [];
    }

    async loadPatterns() {
        for (let pattern of JSON.parse(await requestPromise("https://data.metromobilite.fr/otp/routers/default/index/routes/" + this.id + "/patterns"))) {
            this.patterns.push(new Pattern(pattern.id, pattern.desc));
        }
        return this;
    }

    async loadStops() {
        for (let stop of JSON.parse(await requestPromise("https://data.metromobilite.fr/otp/routers/default/index/routes/" + this.id + "/stops"))) {
            this.stops.push(new Stop(stop.bind, stop.code, stop.name, stop.lat, stop.lon, stop.cluster));
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```